# Installer gives no options for partitioning a FAT32 HDD and hangs at formatting it

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install a second copy of 14.04 (32 bit) to an old IDE 60GB HDD that is already formatted to FAT32.

The installer however does not give me the option of what drive to install to.

It assumes I want to either over write my current 14.04 (64 bit) on my primary drive or install along side.

I want to do neither.

Why isn't there a simple choose another drive for basic install option?

When I choose **Something else...** I cannot change/edit the existing FAT32 partitions on the IDE HDD.  It only allows me to change the partition type to EXT4, etc.  But no resizing.  So I'm forced to use the whole drive with no swap, etc.

Fair enough! Accept and push on.

However when it reaches the window where is eventually says:

> Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #1 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sdc)

it just hangs and the install does not proceed.

Brilliant!!!

What should I actually be doing???

Answer (score 1):

In the end I rebooted to my usual Ubuntu 64 and used gparted to create the required partitions.

The install worked fine after that!